# C++ comparing c string troubles

Tags: c++, string, c-strings

I have written the following code which will does not work but the second snippet will when I change it.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  if( argv[ 1 ] == "-i" )   //This is what does not work
     //Do Something
}
```

But if I write the code like so this will work.

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  string opti = "-i";

  if( argv[ 1 ] == opti )   //This is what does work
     //Do Something
}
```

Is it because the string class has == as an overloaded member and hence can perform this action?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is there any problem in using strcmp? i just wanted to know the advantage to doing this...

Comment: it looks like you're trying to read command line options. If you're on a linux machine check out the getopt() function http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it because the string class has == as an overloaded member and hence can perform this action?

You are correct. Regular values of type `char *` do not have overloaded operators. To compare C strings,

```
if (strcmp(argv[1], "-i") == 0) {
    ...
}
```

By comparing the strings the way you did (with `==` directly), you are comparing the *values* of the pointers. Since `"-i"` is a compile time constant and `argv[1]` is something else, they will never be equal.

Answer (score 9):

Correct. When you do `argv[1] == "-i"` (using == on two `char*` expressions) you're comparing the pointers for equality, not the characters in the string. You have to use the `strcmp` function to compare the string data.

`std::string` has overloaded operators to check string==string, char*==string, and string==char*, but it's impossible to overload char*==char* since that already has a defined meaning: comparing the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

This one will work fine in C. Remember to check argc so you won't get seg fault. There is also strncmp() which is a safer way to compare strings as you limit the max length of the strings.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  if((argc > 1) && (strcmp(argv[1], "-i") == 0))
  {
      printf("got -i\n");
  }
}
```

If you are passing multiple params as command options check out [getopt()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt)