# comparison between std:string and c-string

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to verify the answer(s) given on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2469160/comparison-between-string-literal/36253829#36253829). I have a trouble with them, as the below code shows that effectively the **content** of std::string is compared with the **content** of char[], **not the pointer(s)..** as those answers suggest.

Is this a new feature of C++11? Any help highly appreciated.

```
std::string smth = "hello";
char ch[8] = "hello";
if (ch == smth)
    cout << "yes!";
else
    cout << " no ";

ch[2] = 'W';

if (ch == smth)
    cout << "yes!";
else
    cout << " no ";

ch[2] = 'l';
if (ch == smth)
    cout << "yes!";
else
    cout << " no ";
```

the output is: **yes! no yes!**, while the pointers definitely do not change..

Answer (score 7):

The `std::string` does have an [`operator==` with `char*` pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operators/).

So each time you execute the line:

```
if (ch == smth)
```

You don't just compare pointers, but call a function similar to [strcmp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcmp) that will compare string's and pointer's data and return true if they are similar.

So no, pointers definitely do not change, but their data do. So the operator's result as well.

Answer (score 2):

The ability to compare a `std::string` with a `const char *`, and the result being comparison of the set of characters, is specified in every version of the C++ standard.   Specifically, an `operator==()` and other comparison operators involving a `std::string` as at least one operand is part of the standard.

It is not a feature of any version of C, since `std::string` is not part of the C standard library.   So it is not a feature of C11.

Comment: d r likely was referring to c++11.

Comment: I just responded to the question as asked.    It wouldn't be the first time I've seen someone ask a question based on an assumption of C++-specific features being part of C.   Think how many folks believe they are writing C code, even when they use operator `new`.

Answer (score 1):

The question you linked was comparing two values of type `char*`.  The difference here is that `char*` is a pointer, but `string()` is not a pointer.  When you compare pointers, it checks if the pointers are equal, but since `string()` isn't a pointer, it goes to its `operator==` which checks for equality in the string content itself.